# How is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process related to the error of an exponential moving average?

Tags: time-series, residuals, stochastic-processes, stationarity, exponential-smoothing

Is anyone aware of a direct relationship between the residual of an exponential moving average and the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process? For example, assume a series, $Y_{t}$, that follows a geometric Brownian motion is modelled by the exponential moving average, $S_{t} = \alpha Y_{t} + \left(1-\alpha\right)S_{t-1}$, given some smoothing parameter, $0<\alpha<1$, and initialisation $S_{1}=Y_{1}$.

If we now consider the residual between the series and its exponential moving average, $\epsilon_{t} = Y_{t} - S_{t}$, I believe its evolution can be described in terms of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, $\mathrm{d}\epsilon_{t} = -\theta \epsilon_{t} \mathrm{dt} + \sigma\mathrm{dW}_{t}$. This makes intuitive sense to me, since the residual is, by construction, stationary and mean-reverting with a mean of zero.

I'm trying to understand if the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process of the residual, $\epsilon_{t}$, can be parameterised in terms of the exponential moving average smoothing parameter, $\alpha$. I feel like there's a definite connection between the two, but I haven't been able to find any evidence of it in internet searches. Could it be as simple as $\theta = \left(1-\alpha\right)$? Can any conclusions be drawn about the value of $\sigma$?